# why is my preg_match not working?

Tags: php, preg-match

Here is my code:

```
if(preg_match("/(sleep|drink|beep|@|.com)/i", $content)){
     // get candy
}
```

I'm trying to do get some candy if the `$content` string contains the words `sleep`, `drink`, `beep` or the character `@` or `.com`.

It works for the first 3 words, but not for the `@` or the `.com`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `/` != `|` it's not the same character

Comment: Escape `.` it is a special character.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and will work fine, like this example script and output:

```
<?php

$contents = [
    'go to sleep',
    'I will drink water',
    'this is a beep',
    'test@test.uk',
    'google.com',
    'endswithcom',
    'this doesn\'t match'
];

foreach ($contents as $content) {
    print "content \"$content\" ";
    if (preg_match("/(sleep|drink|beep|@|\\.com)/i", $content)) {
        print " match\n";
    } else {
        print " doesn't match\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
content "go to sleep"  match
content "I will drink water"  match
content "this is a beep"  match
content "test@test.uk"  match
content "google.com"  match
content "endswithcom"  doesn't match
content "this doesn't match"  doesn't match
```

Like @Rizier123 explained, I used `\\.com` instead of only `.com` because the . (dot) is a special character that means any character, on our example the content `endswithcom` will match if we don't escape the dot character. (see [PCRE regex dot syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php))